# Resolve Lambda Issue on Sagemaker Ground truth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to create a labeling job for amazon ground truth for text classification.
I am not able to create it successfully because I keep getting this error -

> MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'PreHumanTaskLambdaArn'
> in params.HumanTaskConfig

Everything seems right, manifest file was successfully created.

I haven't found any help with this issue online, in the documentation, I have found that we could use one of these ARNs in the Text classification section - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_HumanTaskConfig.html

But in the form when creating the labeling job, there's no place to insert this ARN, any idea how this can be fixed and make the error go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SageMaker Ground Truth labeling jobs via the AWS Console (in other words, the AWS website itself) or via API/CLI.

If you want to create your text classification labeling job using the AWS Console, you don’t need to select any lambda ARNs — the console will select the correct lambdas for you.

You only need to specify the `PreHumanTaskLambdaArn` and `AnnotationConsolidationLambdaArn` values if you are 1) launching labeling jobs via API/CLI or 2) creating jobs using the “Custom” task type.

In your case, since you want to create a text classification job, please double-check to confirm that you are selecting the correct Text Classification task type from the menu.

For more information, please refer to the AWS documentation:

- [Text Classification (Single Label) - Amazon SageMaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-text-classification.html)
- [Text Classification (Multi-label) - Amazon SageMaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-text-classification-multilabel.html)